# Check If All Elements in a List Are Equal to Another Value

Tags: python, list, list-manipulation

How do I check if every value in a list is equal to another value, x? For example, if I had a list that was completely full of the number 100, how would I return false based on that condition. Or if a list was full of the number 100 except for one single element which was 88, then I'd want to return true and for the if statement to execute.

Thank you.

Comment: `l.count(x) != len(l)`?

Comment: You could also create a set from the list. If it has one element and that element has value 100 then your original list was all 100s.

Comment: @jarmod This solution is a bit restrictive, though. Now you can only handle hashable types, and building a set probably a bit more costly.

Comment: just return from a function ... `False if len(set(input_list)) == 1 else True` and take `input_list` as argument.

Answer (score 1):

Python has an builtin `any()` function, e.g.:

```
In []:
lst = [100]*5
x = 100
print(lst)
any(a != x for a in lst)

Out[]:
[100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
False

In []:
lst[2] = 88
print(lst)
any(a != x for a in lst)

Out[]:
[100, 100, 88, 100, 100]
True
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use python set to do this , By definition  a set is a well-defined collection of distinct objects,

if len(set(input_list))! =1:
    print "not all items in the set are the same"